# Change navigation drawer's selected item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, selecteditem

[image]

In my app, after selecting "Sell a book", a new activity is opened.
After closing this activity, I need that the navigation drawer will show "My shop" as selected item (like in the picture above).

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a function called in Javascript that uses CSS to hightlight the My Shop button after the user closes the activity.